# onChange method not call when any one property value get changed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to perform some actions when any property value gets changed in the model.

```
struct RoomDataModel: Equatable{
    
    var selectedLocationName : String = ""
    var selectedRoomName : String = ""
    var selectedRoomImage : String = ""
    var roomId: String = ""
    
    static func == (lhs: RoomDataModel, rhs: RoomDataModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.selectedRoomName == rhs.selectedRoomName && lhs.selectedRoomImage == rhs.selectedRoomImage
    }
    
}
```

How I used room object in View :

```
 @State var roomDetail = RoomDataModel()

 var body: some View {
    someview
    .onChange(of: roomDetail) { newValue in
         //performing some action here
    }
}
```

I have the above model which triggers `onChange()` when `selectedRoomName` and `selectedRoomImage` both values changed. but I want to trigger `onChange` even if there is a change in any one of the property values. If I change only `selectedRoomImage` then `onChange()` is not getting triggered.

I am new to SwiftUI and Equatable protocol. I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: "If I change only selectedRoomImage then onChange() is not getting triggered." Cannot reproduce. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: you could just remove the `static func == (lhs: ....`, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` method is not being triggered when only `selectedRoomImage` is changed because the `Equatable` protocol’s `==` function is only checking for equality between the `selectedRoomName` and `selectedRoomImage` properties of the two instances being compared.

To trigger the `onChange` method when any one of the property values changes, you can modify the == function to check for equality between all the properties of the two instances being compared. Here’s an example:

```
static func == (lhs: RoomDataModel, rhs: RoomDataModel) -> Bool {
    return lhs.selectedLocationName == rhs.selectedLocationName &&
           lhs.selectedRoomName == rhs.selectedRoomName &&
           lhs.selectedRoomImage == rhs.selectedRoomImage &&
           lhs.roomId == rhs.roomId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, removing the `static func == ...` from `RoomDataModel`.

Here is the example code that shows it works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var roomDetail = RoomDataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        SomeView(roomDetail: $roomDetail)
            .onChange(of: roomDetail) { newValue in
                print("----> roomDetail: \(roomDetail)") // <-- this will be done on every change
            }
    }
}

struct RoomDataModel: Equatable {
    var selectedLocationName : String = ""
    var selectedRoomName : String = ""
    var selectedRoomImage : String = ""
    var roomId: String = ""
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @Binding var roomDetail: RoomDataModel // <-- here ensure it is @Binding
    
    var body: some View {
        // --- here make any change you like
        VStack {
            TextField("type selectedLocationName", text: $roomDetail.selectedLocationName).border(.red)
            TextField("type selectedRoomName", text: $roomDetail.selectedRoomName).border(.red)
            TextField("type selectedRoomImage", text: $roomDetail.selectedRoomImage).border(.red)
            TextField("type roomId", text: $roomDetail.roomId).border(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the below error After removing static func == ... 

Type 'RoomDataModel' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
Do you want to add protocol stubs?

Comment: I'm on MacOS 13.5, using Xcode 14.3, targeting/testing on ios 16 devices,
 and all works well for me.
Do you get this error using my code (my example) or using your code. If using your code,
 then show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Equality` and `==` and instead conform to `Identifiable` and add `var id: String { roomID }`